# Автоматический выбор источника скринкаста в Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Опция работает только при английском языке:

```
--auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Entire screen
```

Что бы такого прописать чтоб работало и на русском? Работаю через webdriver.